# Create a shortcut under "computer" in home folder Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: home-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a bookmark under “computer” in the Sidebar of the nautilus file manager in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132387/how-to-create-a-bookmark-under-computer-in-the-sidebar-of-the-nautilus-file-ma)

Is there a simple way of creating a "shortcut" to a folder in the home folder under "computer" ( Ubuntu 12.04) ?
Please see the following screenshot. I will clearly explain the issue. What I need is to have a "shortcut" to the folder "Cisco". This "shortcut" should be displayed in the left side column (where the red arrow points) under the other "shortcuts" (Home, Desktop, Documents, ...) 
How do you create a "shortcut" to this "Cisco" folder, "shortcut" located under "computer". Seems like an easy task... but I could not figure out how to do that ??

[image]

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You can see this question:

[How to create a bookmark under “computer” in the Sidebar of the nautilus file manager in 12.04?][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132387/how-to-create-a-bookmark-under-computer-in-the-sidebar-of-the-nautilus-file-ma

Answer (score 8):

Enter the folder then Ctrl+D, it will create a bookmark under the Bookmarks category in the sidebar.