# How do I customize the home folder launcher in the sidebar?

Tags: unity, 12.10, launcher

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and for my side bar **Home Folder** launcher, I want to use different bookmarks. I have my Music, Pictures and Videos on another drive and want the default ones to link to those folders on the other drive instead. How can I set which folders I want to use for the **Home Folder** launcher button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, It's simple. This question is very similar  but I'm ok with the **Bookmarks** area [How to create a bookmark under "computer" in the Sidebar of the nautilus file manager in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132387/how-to-create-a-bookmark-under-computer-in-the-sidebar-of-the-nautilus-file-ma)

Go in the folder you want and just click on **Bookmarks** -> **Add Bookmark** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve using this alternate way. You can go for folder synchronization where both folders are on the same HDD. In [How to synchronize folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147234/how-to-synchronize-folders) is a solution which shows folder synchronization between internal HDD to external HDD but you can just change the path of destination and you will achieve what you need. This is just an alternate way. I don't know how to edit the link of home folder itself.